# Load only necessary data Linq to Sql and ExpandoObject

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to reduce the sql server calls from the following (simplified) query:

```
var timequery = from t in TimeRecords
                select t;

var reducedResults = timequery.Select(delegate(TimeRecord t){

    ExpandoObject result = new ExpandoObject();
    IDictionary<string,object> record = (IDictionary<string,object>)result;

    record["DisplayName"] = t.User.DisplayName; //this loads ENTIRE user record

   //Include Dynamic columns
   foreach (var expenseTypeDescription in usedExpenseTypes) //the usedExpenseTypes are the types in the results 
   {    
       //also loading entire expense and expense type records
       record[expenseType] = t.Expenses.Where(e => e.ExpenseType.Description = expenseTypeDescription ).Sum(e => e.Amount);
   }

   return (dynamic)result;
}).ToList();
```

If it makes any difference I will do `reducedResults.OrderBy(t => t.Copies).Skip(page).Take(pageSize)`, where copies is one of the expense types in the dynamic columns, later on in the code. So, I don't want to pull all the results into memory before paging.

When I look at the generated sql, instead of pulling just the user displayname, it's completely populating the User record to get just the display name. I tried to cast through an anonymous type to get just the displayname, but then I can't use the `delegate(TimeRecord t)`. Not using the delegate would be fine, but I don't know how to do the dynamic columns from the expense types with `timequery.Select(t => new { t.User.DisplayName, //dynamic columns });`

To summarize, how can I not load the entire User record?

Edit: 
The Simplified types are

```
class TimeRecord
{
     User User;
     EntitySet<Expense> Expenses;
     //other stuff
}

class User
{
     string DisplayName;
     //other stuff
}

class Expense
{
    decimal Amount;
    ExpenseType ExpenseType;
    //other stuff
}

class ExpenseType
{
     string Description;
     //other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont need the entire user entity, create a type that contains just the fields you need and cast to it

```
public class UserInfo
{
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    //include anything else you may need.
}

var timequery = from t in TimeRecords
                select new UserInfo
                {
                 DisplayName = t.User.DisplayName
                 };
```

Comment: It's not casting, that's a different concept entirely. I would call it projecting.

Comment: How would I get the dynamic expense columns doing this? or would I then call the dynamic code and build off of it?

Comment: @SumGuy no, that would get only the displayname and you would loose access to any other data you are later querying from it. can you post your table structure or class declaration...

Comment: @Rickjames I added the classes, simplified, I'll be expanding to other table data besides User in the end, but will approach them all the same way, so that would just be unneeded complexity for the question

Comment: It sounds like I need to build a simplified class structure and project into it, then do the expandoObject after, gonna try that. I tried just projecting onto a dynamic, but it didn't like the expenses list

Comment: @SumGuy That would be the way i would go. Much better IMHO than pulling lots of data that you dont need. Most likely better for performance too.